# Finding partly hidden ball in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing, hough-transform

I'm using OpenCV in an attempt of tracking a ball on a Bonzini table.

Converting the color to HSV and providing an upper and lower Scalar `(25,90,90)` and `(30,255,255)` I can find the ball when it is fully or almost fully visible.

The problem is when it is only partly visible. I tried to use HoughCircles to find the ball, but I'm not having any luck. While it is sometimes finding the ball, most of the time it just sees random circles everywhere - maybe this isn't the right way to go about it?

**How do I locate the center of the ball when it is only partly visible (given that the radius of the ball is always the same)?**

[image: 1]]

#### HoughCircles code

```
Mat gray;

vector<Vec3f> circles;

bilateralFilter(frame, gray, 15, 1000, 1000);
cvtColor(gray, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(9,9), 2, 2);

HoughCircles(gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 200, 50, 10, 12, 24);
```

Comment: This is in video, correct? Is the camera fixed? That second example looks like a really difficult problem, there is hardly any visible ball in that frame at all. Hough circles is not going to help you much when there is virtually no circle to detect in the image.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds This is a video yes, and the camera is fixed. The second example is also the worst example I ever found. It is rarely ever that hidden.

Comment: So it will of course only be that hidden for a couple frames at a time. You will probably not be able to deal with occlusion that large. What I would do is simply follow the ball's trajectory, since you can calculate the position, speed, direction of the ball from the prior frames. You should be able to save the ball locations from the previous few frames and guess where the ball would be in that frame, and then go onto the next frame. If you're getting false circles, you should increase `param2`; if you *don't* detect a Hough circle, then just follow the trajectory for that frame.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds An excellent point, I think I will work towards calculating the most probable location of the ball based on the balls trajectory, this should be quite easy given the fixed position of the camera. Once again, thanks. Feel free to make it an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Sure, I'll add it as an answer. I also have an alternative approach you might try too, along the same lines.

Comment: Use ball old positions to calculate it's trajectory and probability of being in some area of space. Than sort founded contours by distance from that area and by contourArea.

Comment: if you can segment the different objects well you can reduce the possible (occluded) ball locations to very few possibilities. This should make a teacking much easier and if there is at least a little bit of yellow ball visible you can reduce the number of possible circles further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Occlusion is difficult in general to deal with, but having a fixed camera location gives you a little lee-way. You can easily calculate the trajectory of the ball from previous frames to know where it is *likely* to appear. If you use Hough circles, you can set `param2` to be decently high so you're *not* getting false positives. Then whenever Hough circles doesn't detect a circle, i.e., `circles` is empty, you can use the prior frame positions to guess where the ball is during the occlusion.

If you're filtering your image by color, you will get a binary image which can be processed in a number of ways. Since you can calculate the ball size, you can easily use Hough circles in normal frames but this won't help you during occlusion; and template matching isn't likely to either. Instead, you'll need to use other approaches of grouping together those indicator points from your binary image.

Along the same lines you could *not* use Hough circles and just get the centers by looking for clustering with `kmeans` or similar in the binary image, and you can get the center of the cluster from that. The center could be compared with the predicted trajectory in some way. For example if the number of indicator pixels you get from your binary image filtering the yellow is too low, then you could simply rely on the predicted trajectory. Even more robust (I think) you could make a weighted average of the predicted trajectory with the center of the cluster, where the weight is given by the number of indicator pixels in the binary image. That way if you have no occlusion, you're getting most or all of the position based on the center of your indicator pixels; if you have *some* occlusion, you're adding a bit of correction via your supposed trajectory; and if you have a *lot* of occlusion, you can rely heavily on the predicted trajectory.

The above can similarly work with `contours` as well; again since you know the size of the ball, you can see how large your contours are with `contourArea`, and weight the center of your contours with your predicted trajectory based on the ratio of the contour area and the full circle area. @Green_Wizard's suggestion is also great for making sure you're finding contours in the right area. This is a reverse approach from my suggestion, where you look at the predicted trajectory *first*, and try to detect something in that limited area or sort indications by distance to that. I did something similar in a template matching project, but it was mostly for computational reduction---I defined an ROI based around the last known location of the template which grew in size until the template was found again. [See for e.g.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m99H6oH46E8). I did *not* include predicted trajectory in this though as, at least for Mario, he doesn't actually move forward; the level moves backwards.